# MySql is not recognizing some Table Columns after uploading on Domain

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have created a website using codeigniter Framework. Its working perfectly fine on localhost. Queries are fetching the data and showing the desired result. But after i uploaded the website on my Domain, its giving weird error messages. The same query is working fine on localhost but generating error messages on Domain database PhpMyAdmin.

Some queries are working fine, like User login queries and some other basic queries, but queries containing complex joining generating error messages only on Domain..

The following query is working perfeclty fine on localhost but generating missing column error message on Domain DB.

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Semester_courses.SemisterCourseId' in 'on clause'

SELECT sum( student_marks.FinalMarks ) , semester_courses.in_semester, 
student_marks.StudentId FROM student_marks 
JOIN semester_courses
ON student_marks.SemisterCourseId = Semester_courses.SemisterCourseId 
WHERE 
semester_courses.in_semester =1 
GROUP BY semester_courses.in_semester , student_marks.StudentId 
order by student_marks.FinalMarks Desc 
Limit 0,1

Filename: /home/tahakirmani/public_html/ums/models/loginmodel.php

Line Number: 1523
```

Comment: What's the output of `DESCRIBE Semester_courses;` (note the case on that output aswell)? Your `GROUP BY` suggests `semester_courses` should be lower case while it's uppercase in your `ON`.

Comment: #1146 - Table 'secs.Semester_courses' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using upper- and lowercase table names in your query for `semester_courses`:

Change `Semeter_courses` in the `ON` part of your `JOIN` to lowercase and you should be fine (given your field names are spelled correctly):

```
SELECT sum( student_marks.FinalMarks ), semester_courses.in_semester, student_marks.StudentId
FROM student_marks 
JOIN semester_courses
ON student_marks.SemisterCourseId = semester_courses.SemisterCourseId 
WHERE semester_courses.in_semester = 1 
GROUP BY semester_courses.in_semester, student_marks.StudentId 
ORDER BY student_marks.FinalMarks DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks..I just copy and paste your code and got the result without any error message, but still i am unable to understand why it was working fine on localhost?

Comment: Probably other mysql settings (or did you mitigate from a windows machine to a unix machine?)

Comment: I am using windows on my system and linux on my webhosting server.

Comment: That's probably it. Table names (and their files) aren't case sensitive on Windows, they are however on unix based machines.